# How can I delete items in one context from another in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

EssaieFilament is the name of a table in my database.

note: I translated the error msg from french, so its might not be exact.

Hello, I fill up a list of "EssaieFilament", then send the list to a function that delet them but as the context change, it's give me a error.

> L'exception System.InvalidOperationException happened
>   HResult=0x80131509   Message=Impossible to delet the object, as its can't be
>   found in ObjectStateManager.   Source=EntityFramework

Is there a ways to fix this without actually have to send the context?

```
public static void SupprimerEssaieFilament(List<EssaieFilament> essaieFilament_list)
{
    using (var context = new tp2_1608469Entities1())
    {
        foreach (EssaieFilament essaieFilament in essaieFilament_list)
        {
            context.EssaieFilaments.Remove(essaieFilament);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post exception messages in French, this is an English site

Comment: my bad, translated it in english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something with [.AttachTo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/03/27/tip-9-how-to-delete-an-object-without-retrieving-it/) in this situation, where you attach your list of entities to the new context and then delete them.

You can also re-query the new context and delete the found items. This will perform much better than the code in your example, since you delete all items at once in a single call, instead of once-per-item in your collection.

```
public static void SupprimerEssaieFilament(List<EssaieFilament> essaieFilament_list)
{
    using (var context = new tp2_1608469Entities1())
    {
        var itemIds = essaieFilament_list.Select(x=>x.Id);
        var itemsToDelete = context.EssaieFilaments.Where(x=>itemsIds.Contains(x.Id));

        context.EssaieFilaments.RemoveRange(itemsToDelete);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your edit was needed. Creating the items and only putting the Id should actually be enough. Why did you change that?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know, right. It's been a few months since I've used EF and I couldn't remember if .RemoveRange worked with fakes.  I can't find any articles to support it so I played it safe.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work like this. You are opening a new context (connection to the DataBase), but the entities that you have retrieved belong to another connection (the one in the first method, where you have queried them).

You should either send the context to the method, or send a list of Id's, and when you open the new context, retrieve the entities, and then delete (or whatever you want to do) them.

Answer (score -1):

If the context changes, you have to check if the `essaieFilament` object you want to delete **exists** in the context before delete it... So try this:

```
public static void SupprimerEssaieFilament(List<EssaieFilament> essaieFilament_list)
{
    using (var context = new tp2_1608469Entities1())
    {
        foreach (EssaieFilament essaieFilament in essaieFilament_list)
        {
            if (context.EssaieFilaments.Contains(essaieFilament))
            {
                context.EssaieFilaments.Remove(essaieFilament);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, `EssaieFilaments` is not a list, you should not check whether the object exists. This would be correct in a `List<T>`, not in a `DbSet<T>`